# PHP7 extensions aren't reading correctly from config file

Tags: php, php.ini, php7

I'm setting up a WordPress installation on my Windows server. I have an IIS site set up to look at the correct folder. Right now, in the folder is a php_info file so that I can see which PHP is installed. I personally installed PHP 7.2.8. However, when I look for the php_info file in the address bar, it shows the php info page with the version being 7.2.2. The Loaded Configuration file has to correct file path of the folder I uploaded. The environmental path is pointing to `D:\PHP\PHP7` (which is correct). So I'm not sure why this is happening. The biggest issue is that there are some extensions that I need to enable (that are, indeed enabled in the ini file) that aren't showing on php info page.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: How did you install PHP? How did you install the _other_ version of PHP?

Comment: Well it was actually installed for me by our server crew. This is also a new server. No other php versions have been installed on here ever.

Comment: You should have a chat with the server crew first, before talking to us.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. I thought I had 7.2.8 but it *is* actually 7.2.2. As for the extensions problem:

I solved the extensions problem. My php.ini file was pointed to the wrong ext folder. I updated it and now the correct extensions are showing up on the info page.

Where to update in the PHP.ini file: Search for the [WebPIChanges] header. The extension_dir is what you want to update.